# How to keep an overview over the dependency injection stuff?

Tags: java, eclipse, guice

How do you keep an overview over which objects get injected where? I have a rather small project where i use guice, not so much because i really need it (given the project is still small), but rather because i want to get to know it a little better.

**I am already starting to loose the overview with only ~10 classes; are there tools that analyze the code to show something like a dependency graph?**

That would make it easier to see quickly where i forgot something or where i need singleton scoped injection. Also with guice a lot of things happen implicitly, being able to see these things explicitly would help debugging in the future.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have a couple of principles which help to manage dependencies using Guice.

1. Keep *all* bindings inside modules *only*. Do not use just-in-time bindings stuff. I mean, do not use `@Singleton` or `@ImplementedBy` or `@ProvidedBy`, i.e. all that is described [here](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/JustInTimeBindings). Try also always call `binder.requireExplicitBindings()` at the top of your modules - it will force you to always bind your dependencies explicitly. When you keep all dependencies to the modules, you can easily find which interface fulfilled by which implementation. This simplifies navigation around bindings *a lot*.
2. Try to keep your modules as small as possible, and then combine them when creating an injector (directly via `createInjector()` call or using a central module which does nothing but `install()`s other modules). Each module should be responsible for its own part of the application and should be named accordingly. Also your modules should not contain complex initialization and dynamic binding code. This way you will be able to find a module which is responsible for some part of your application quite easily.

These principles are really simple but they make dependency management very easy.

Also, you can visualize dependency graph using [special Guice extension](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/Grapher). It has it bugs though, and it has been a while since I have used it, so I can't give you exact links on how to avoid these bugs, but googling for it won't take long.

Comment: I agree about `@ImplementedBy` and `@ProvidedBy`, but I actually prefer putting scope annotations like `@Singleton` on the classes themselves. That way it's easy to see any thread-safety requirements the class may have directly.

Comment: @TavianBarnes, JSR-305 provides special annotations which determine the kind of thread safety: `@Immutable`, `@ThreadSafe` and `@NotThreadSafe`. I prefer to use them to indicate thread safety of my classes. Also using `@Singleton` on classes can lead to confusing results when for some reason you need to override the scope. Your point is still valid, though.

Comment: Good point, maybe I'll start using those actually.  Another thing the scope annotations are useful for is as a reminder not to inject `@RequestScoped` things directly (without `Provider<>`) into `@Singleton`s, for example.  But it's true that you could get confused if the `Module` overrides that scope.  Maybe Guice should have a mode that prohibits that.